# API 23 Local position is not available

Tags: java, android, location

I try to get the country where the device is currently, to get this information, I use the LocationManager as follow:

```java
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    Log.d(TAG, "Network: " + location);
    if(location == null){
      location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
      Log.d(TAG, "GPS: " + location);
    }
```

In my XML I inserted the neccesarry permissions:

```xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Of course, I ask for these permissions at Runtime.
My problem is that my target devices always gives me `null` and I don't know why. But there is an other location app installed, which also downloads map pieces. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't define country directly thru `LocationManager` because the `Location` class doesn't contains such data:

```
/**
 * A data class representing a geographic location.
 *
 * <p>A location can consist of a latitude, longitude, timestamp,
 * and other information such as bearing, altitude and velocity.
 *
 * <p>All locations generated by the {@link LocationManager} are
 * guaranteed to have a valid latitude, longitude, and timestamp
 * (both UTC time and elapsed real-time since boot), all other
 * parameters are optional.
 */
public class Location implements Parcelable {
```

You can define current `latitude` & `longitude` and make a request to some third-party API to define country name by those coordinates.

---

Obviously `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation` returns `null` because last known location of this device for your applications is undefined.

```
/**
 * Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known
 * location fix obtained from the given provider.
 *
 * <p> This can be done
 * without starting the provider.  Note that this location could
 * be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and
 * moved to another location.
 *
 * <p> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.
 *
 * @param provider the name of the provider
 * @return the last known location for the provider, or null
 *
 * @throws SecurityException if no suitable permission is present
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if provider is null or doesn't exist
 */
@RequiresPermission(anyOf = {ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION})
public Location getLastKnownLocation(String provider) {
```

As far you use `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` it doesn't always matter that any other application on this device uses location data. 
To be able to reuse location data received by other applications on this device properly please read about [fused location provider](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/)

Comment: You are right, but this is not my problem, I already have a class, which gets the current country out of the coordinates.
As you can see my question is about the not available Information.
In detail this means the `null` value of location.

Comment: At first check that `use location` is enabled on your device.

Comment: Also you are requiesting `lastKnownLocation` at some period of time directly. It is not guaranteed that at this moment location was already defined. IMHO it's better to subscribe for receiving location updates as they defined by device. How to achieve this - read on `Fused Location Provider API` web page